# How to run Java3D on RPi 2

Tags: java, java-3d, raspberry-pi2

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 2 and have been trying to get a program using Java/Java 3D that I've used before on the previous Model B to run on it.

The Pi is running Raspbian, and I've installed the `libjava3d-java` and `libjava3d-jni` packages.

I've copied the following files into a `lib` folder:

```
j3dcore.jar
j3dutils.jar
vecmath.jar
libj3dcore-ogl.so
```

I've then included `-Djava.library.path="lib/*"` in the command I use to run my program, but I'm getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path`

Could there be any other files that I need? Might I have an incorrect version of the native libraries? All the files I've put in the `lib` folder are ones that I've found in the system as installed by the package manager.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're trying to install an obsolete version of Java3D (1.5.2 or earlier). Please follow [these instructions](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D) to download and install Java3D 1.6.0.

Java3D uses the fixed pipeline, it is designed to use OpenGL whereas the Raspberry Pi supports OpenGL ES. Java3D 1.6.0 uses mostly the same public API than Java3D 1.5.2 and we have done no change to make it work with OpenGL ES. It has a very few chances to work as is on your device.

Rather use JMonkeyEngine 3, LibGDX or JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation with its JOGL renderer. The two first ones work with the Raspberry Pi for sure, the last one still needs some work.

Edit.: You have a chance to make it work with Eric Anholt's driver, it already works with Processing 3 on a Raspberry Pi 2: http://labb.zafena.se/?p=972